# pandas.read_excel() ImportError: cannot import name 'TYPE_BOOL'

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I have recently tried to work on excel spreadsheets through python, but when I try to import them I get this error:

ImportError: cannot import name 'TYPE_BOOL' from 'openpyxl.cell.cell' (C:\Users\frank\Anaconda3\envs\tsa_course\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\cell\cell.py)

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
pd.read_excel('C:/Users/frank/OneDrive/Desktop/Random_Files/Lista_misa_mara.xlsx')
```

I am having no problem reading CSV files, but I don't know why I am having this problem with excel files.

It is also worth mentioning that I have tried to import excel files without success in both my base virtual environment and in another virtual environment that I used for a course where I was constantly importing CSV and sometimes excel files to python.

Also, I have accessed this file:

*(C:\Users\frank\Anaconda3\envs\tsa_course\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\cell\cell.py)*,
which is referenced in the ImportError, and I can see the class called 'TYPE_BOOL' but I don't know why it can't be imported.

Summary: How can I get rid of this 'cannot import name 'TYPE_BOOL'' error when reading an excel file?

Comment: We'll need to some a bit more about your current environment: how did you set it up (virtualenv, pipenv, conda, ...), what did you install, and specifically, what versions are you using (both Python and the relevant packages: numpy and pandas, and probably also openpyxl). Most versions can be found by importing the package and the get the `__version__` package attribute, e.g. `numpy.__version__` or `pandas.__version__`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will stop using the virtual environment I used for my course and will work on my base environment. Here (in my base environment) I am running:
python 3.7.1
pandas 1.2.1
numpy 1.18.5
openpyxl 2.5.12